# Django-notification set up issue

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to django and i've just installed django-notifications into my project. Now I've set it up, installed it and added this signal

```
notify_send = request.user.profile.get_absolute_url()
notify.send(notify_send, recipient=pending_like, verb='Sent you a friend request' )
```

this works perfectly when some likes another user, so i then have a look in /inbox/notifications/ and i see the notification

tomsmith Sent You a Friend Request

1 minute ago

None"

So it works perfectly, however how do i make it so that tomsmith is clickable and the person viewing it can click on the name to go to his profile? Is this the action object? also what does the None stand for? sorry if this is confusing but i cant get my head around it.

I have a profile app under under the name profiles with this model,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=LOCATIONS,null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.user.username


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        url = reverse("profile", kwargs={"username": self.user.username})
        return url

    def like_link(self):
        url = reverse("like_user", kwargs={"id": self.user.id})
        return url`
```

my error code is:

> AttributeError at /like/13/ 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'
>   Request Method:   GET

in the traceback

> notify.send(notify_send, recipient=pending_like, verb='Sent you a
>   friend request' )

and

> actor_content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(actor),

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I think "None" hear means that you have missed some parameter or have supplied a parameter in "notify.send" method call where the parameter value is null(in case of python its None).

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to define a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) (in the `Profile` model) for each profile and then to use it in `notify.send`:

```
notify_send = (request.user.profile, ...)
```

but in notification instead of ***tomsmith*** you would have ***the_link_to tomsmith_profile***.

EDIT

Redefie your `__unicode__` like:

```
def __unicode__(self): 
    return self.user.get_absolute_url(self)
```

Comment: Thanks" however i now get the error 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: this is the get_absolute_url

Comment: `def get_absolute_url(self):  
url = reverse("profile", kwargs={"username": self.user.username})
return url`

Comment: @caldf try `def get_absolute_url(self):` `return reverse('profile', args =[self.user.username])`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain doru, but that didnt work. This is my profile model.
`class Profile(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=LOCATIONS,null=True, blank=True)
 picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)


 def __unicode__(self): 
  return self.user.username


 def get_absolute_url(self):
  url = reverse("profile", kargs={"username": self.user.username})
  return url

 def like_link(self):
  url = reverse("like_user", kwargs={"id": self.user.id})
  return url
`

Comment: this is my signal, `notify.send(notify_send, recipient=pending_like, verb='Sent you a friend request' )`

Comment: and `notify_send = request.user.profile.get_absolute_url()`

Comment: @caldf you should put the code into your question to be more visible

Comment: sorry as you can tell im very new to all this, ive updated it now, thank you for your help i really appreciate it!

Comment: I've added what i think you asked for